# Rising sea level: flooding of iconic buildings

Tags: oceanography, geography, sea-level

I realize that this question may be arguably off-topic, but there doesn't seem to be a stack exchange specific to oceanography, geography, or architecture.

With rising sea level in mind, how high above sea level are the front doors of 'at risk' iconic structures, such as the One World Trade Center in New York, the Opera House in Sydney, and the Shanghai Tower? If it is true that sea level will ultimately rise not less than six metres (albeit not for several centuries hence), then will these buildings all become islands?

Comment: Two things: (1) Will such buildings last several centuries regardless of rising sea levels? (2) Most of those building have basement levels for utilities, car parking etc. Flooding of the basements may render the buildings unusable or they may need to install  pumps, as some buildings already have in the downtown Perth (Western Australia), that are near the Swan River.

Comment: A better question: what about flooding of Trump's properties?

Comment: You only give some examples of *iconic examples*, which makes this question quite arbitrary. Nothing stops you from Googling the name of the building in combination with the word *elevation*. This will e.g. show you that the elevation for the Opera House in Sydney is 7 meters (the links often *also* give you the height of the structure).